# Webpack-dev-server not bundling even after showing bundle valid message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've set up a basic react application with webpack but I couldn't get the `webpack-dev-server` running properly.

I've installed `webpack-dev-server` globally and tried running the command `sudo webpack-dev-server --hot` as hot reloading was required.

The project seems to be working fine with just `webpack` cmd. It builds into my build folder and I can get it working via some server but it wont work with `webpack-dev-server`. From terminal its clear that the build process has completed with no error being thrown [`webpack: bundle is now VALID.`] and its in fact watching properly because on any change it does trigger the build process but it doesn't really gets built [it doesn't serve my bundle.js]. I tried changing the entire config and still couldn't get the issue resolved.

It would be much appreciated if someone can help.

Following is my webpack.config.js file.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: '#inline-source-map"',

    watch: true,
    colors: true,
    progress: true,

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: "babel",
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            ],
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            query: {
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            }
        }, {
            loader: 'style!css!sass',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            test: /\.scss$/
        }]
    },

    plugins: [],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build/js'),
        publicPath: '/build/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            './src/index.js'
        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./",
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
};
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've got the issue resolved by myself. Silly as it sounds but the issue was with the `publicPath` under the `output` object. It should match the `path` property instead of just `/build/`, i.e.,

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build/js'),
    publicPath: '/build/js', // instead of publicPath: '/build/' 
    filename: '[name].js'
},
```

Comment: Thank you! Been having the same issue and no tuts or docs have mentioned this! Cheers!

Comment: I might add based on what I'm seeing, that your public path should have a trailing slash. When using the technique described in Andre Evangelista's answer, I could see that webpack dev server was serving my js file from `distmain.js` rather than `dist/main.js`.

Comment: Ay, I'm glad this still is helping people.

Answer (score 32):

In my case I had to check where the webpack is serving the file.

You can see it: 
`http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server`

Then I could see my bundle.js path > http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js

After that I used that `/dist/bundle.js` in my index.html `<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>`

Now it refreshes any file changes.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Comment: I was able to figure out karthik-rana 's answer *because of* of this answer. Thanks @andre-evangelista. And +1 for the answer!

Comment: Thanks  a lot!! great,  you help me found the problem !! :)

Comment: This actually explains it (+1). I ended up changing publicPath as the accepted answer suggested, *but it does not need to match the output path* (mine doesn't).

Answer (score 19):

webpack-dev-server serves your bundle.js from memory. It won't generate the file when you run it. So bundle.js is not present as a file in this scenario.

If you wan't to use bundle.js, for example to optimize it's size or test your production deployment, generate it with webpack using the webpack command and serve it in production mode.

Comment: Hi.. thank you for the response.. I'm aware of the fact that the file won't be generated. In my case its not serving from memory, ie, I'm not getting the updates on my localhost.

Comment: in this case please double check wether the path of bundle.js in your script tag in your html is right.

Comment: Yes its correct and I believe that's why i'm getting it working while I do `webpack`. . In my case its `build/js/bundle.js`

Answer (score 5):

By the way, started from Webpack v4 it is possible to write in-memory assets to disk:

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./",
    port: 8080,
    writeToDisk: true
  }
```

See [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-).

Answer (score 5):

The fix to this for me was:

```
  devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    }
  }
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-

Answer (score 1):

Dev-server keeps the compiled file in memory, and I can't access it directly...
BUT! THE SOLUTION is that you have no need to access it, in development(even when you run your project on node server or localhost) use localhost:8080 to access your page, and that's where webpack-dev-server is serving your page and you can feel all advantages of using it(live reload!),  BUT! it doesn't compile your bundle.js, SO! before production, you need to manually run webpack build command, and that's it! there is no way for dev-server to compile your bundle.js file! Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this - https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/24
According to this, webpack dev server no longer writes to the disk. So, you wont be able to see the build file. Instead, it will be served from the memory. To get it working you have to set the proper path.
Example: in index.html loads the build file from '/dist/main.js' so in webpack config file set the output.publicPath to '/dist/'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30169678)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using VS Code and I had to restart it. I have noticed that vs code bugs up sometimes. The changes you make in configuration files (package.json, webpack.config.js etc.) do not take effect sometimes. So, in case you encounter a situation where something doesn't work even with the correct settings, just restart vs code.

I can't see any bug reports related to this. So that's strange. I'm thinking this bug is triggered if you change one of the configuration files some time later after you have already built the project multiple times.

If this is actually what's happening then it's a huge bug. I'll try switching to Visual Studio instead of Code and see if this still happens. If it does then it's probably an issue with webpack.